# Not been able to give role based permission in drools guvnor using jboss AS 7

Tags: authorization, jaas, role-based, drools-guvnor, role-base-authorization

I am in a BRMS technology project in financial sector. Using Drools Guvnor 5.5.0.Final with jboss-as-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT server. I configured the login page in guvnor using jaas successfully. Now I need to have the role Based Permission. But not been able to implement it yet. The beans,xml is

```
  <security:IdentityImpl>
    <s:modifies/>

    <!-- No real authentication: demo authentication for demo purposes -->
    <!--<security:authenticatorClass>org.drools.guvnor.server.security.DemoAuthenticator</security:authenticatorClass>-->

    <!-- JAAS based authentication --> 
    <security:authenticatorName>jaasAuthenticator</security:authenticatorName>

    <!-- IDM based authentication (supports LDAP, see Seam 3 and PicketLink IDM documentation) -->
    <!--<security:authenticatorClass>org.jboss.seam.security.management.IdmAuthenticator</security:authenticator>-->
  </security:IdentityImpl>

  <security:jaas.JaasAuthenticator>
    <s:modifies/>
    <!--
      The following one will use the jaas configuration called "other",
      which in jboss AS means you can use properties files for users.
    -->
    <s:jaasConfigName>other</s:jaasConfigName>
  </security:jaas.JaasAuthenticator>


  <!-- SECURITY AUTHORIZATION CONFIGURATION -->
  <!--
      This is used to enable or disable role-based authorization. By default it is disabled.
  -->
    <component name="org.jboss.seam.security.permission.PermissionResolver">
        <property name="enableRoleBasedAuthorization">true</property>
        </component>
```

AND THE standalone.xml is

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="defaultUsersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="defaultRolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

I don't know what am I missing. Can anyone suggest me over the same. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue. The issue was with one of the class file of seam and configuration of beans.xml

Comment: Hi, R.K.R. I have a colleague who's interested in your solution. Are you able to explain what  changes in seam and in the beans.xml that you had to make? Perhaps the details would help him. And others, I suppose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, three specific Drools changes were required to get Drools Guvnor 5.5.0.Final working with JBoss EAP 6 (which is based on AS 7.1 and should translate to AS 7.2): fix the XML, replace seam-security, and patch a Guvnor file.

In beans.xml, the `jaasConfigName` tag specifies no namespace and causes an error.  Fix this by changing `jaasConfigName` to `security:jaasConfigName`.

```xml
<security:jaas.JaasAuthenticator>
  <s:modifies/>
  <!--
    The following one will use the jaas configuration called "other",
    which in jboss AS means you can use properties files for users.
  -->
  <security:jaasConfigName>other</security:jaasConfigName>
</security:jaas.JaasAuthenticator>
```

The version of Seam Security used by Guvnor contains a bug.  To fix this, modify the Guvnor WAR: replace `seam-security-3.1.0.Final.jar` with `seam-security-3.2.0.Final.jar` and `seam-security-api-3.1.0.Final.jar` with `seam-security-api-3.2.0.Final.jar`.

Guvnor's SecurityServiceImpl class contains a bug.  To fix this, patch and recompile the class as per http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-configure-Guvnor-5-4-JAAS-with-jboss-7-0-2-tp4020424p4020854.html

Note that the Seam Security and SecurityServiceImpl bugs have been resolved on the Guvnor 5.5.x branch on GitHub (https://github.com/droolsjbpm/guvnor/tree/5.5.x), so the easiest solution for those problems might be to download and build the latest version.  (That's what I did.)

With these changes in place, both authentication and role-base authorization should work.  In my test environment I demonstrated package-restricted developer access.

See https://community.jboss.org/thread/206645, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/GUVNOR-1989, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/GUVNOR-1976, http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-configure-Guvnor-5-4-JAAS-with-jboss-7-0-2-td4020424.html, and http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-Error-JAAS-Authentication-with-Guvnor-5-5-0-and-Authorization-Error-tt4023826.html for background info.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication in place for guvnor visit following link.

https://community.jboss.org/message/817783#817783